# Get the svn revision less than a given number?

Tags: svn, revision-history

I am using windows OS only. I need a command to get the last revision which is less than or equal to a given revision number. Eg. latest rev = 300. The other revs = 290, 289, 280 etc.
If i search for <= 285, then I should get 280 only. Is there a command for this ?

I googled and found no answer. One solution might be to use `svn log --limit 100  http://svn.repo1.com/trunk/app`. Hopefully, the required number lies within the last 100 revisions, otherwise I will get no results. Then, parse through each of the 100 results, extract only the revision number while discarding all the presentation, comments etc. Then, look for the desired number in a list of 100 numbers. But, this is a very inefficient way. Please suggest something quick and easy.

Comment: You could try the revision log dialogue in TortoiseSVN to see if that does what you need? You could also use the --xml switch on the svn log command to output to xml and then use a different program to parse that or convert it to a spreadsheet and search that way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
svn log http://your_repo/subdirectory/file -r 285:0 -l 1
```

will output the log for the first (`-l 1`) revision that affected `subdirectory/file` when counting from commit 185 backwards to the first commit (`-r 285:0`).

Comment: Is it also possible to get 285 as well in the results ? I know I asked only for 280. But, I want to learn how to get 285 in the results as well. Thank you very much !

Comment: If 285 changed the file you display the log for, then it should be the only revision that is displayed. If it didn't, it will never be shown in that log. I think it's best to issue a second command if you want to have 285 too.

Comment: sorry for my foolish questions. I am a beginner in source control/svn. I am not able to understand what you said. Please tell me why my request will give wrong answers. thanks

Comment: Revisions in Subversion represent the state of the whole repository. If you run `git log` on a particular file or directory, only the revisions where it was altered are displayed. That's why your revision list has gaps. If revision 285 is not displayed, that means that while *some* files in the repository changed in that revision, the one you did display the log for did not. See e.g. [here](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.basic.in-action.html#svn.basic.in-action.revs) for details.